# How to load a MongoDB collection onto a Java program data structure, after saving it?

Tags: java, arrays, database, mongodb, nosql

I started using monogDB to save and load files in my java program, but i'm having trouble loading back the database into my program. My save method completely works and creates the Mongo Database when i checked through Mongo Compass, my main problem is that i want it to load back those database values into my array which stores all information when running the code.

***Right now when I close and open the Java code and enter the load method it does not retrieve the saved entries***

```
  private static void loadFile(String[] name) {
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = (MongoClient) MongoClients.create(System.getProperty("mongodb.uri"))) {
            MongoDatabase sampleTrainingDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDB");
            MongoCollection<Document> gradesCollection = sampleTrainingDB.getCollection("collection");

            // find one document with new Document
            Document document = gradesCollection.find(new Document("title", "Customer")).first();
        }
    }
```

These are the values stored in my string array

`[Jacky, Becky, Becky, vacant, Jacky, amy, vacant, vacant, amy, vacant, Jackie, vacant, vacant, Jackie, Jackie, Annie, vacant, vacant, Annie, vacant, Maria, vacant, vacant, Maria, vacant, vacant, Maria, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant, vacant]`

Heres a picture of my MongoDB : [View_Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et3Oz.png)

[image]

I just need it to load it back to my array so that my program can remember the previous entries.

***This is how i save the file ***

```
private static void saveFile(String[] name) {

        // Creating a Mongo client
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

        // Creating Credentials
        MongoCredential credential;
        credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "trainDb",
                "password".toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");

        //Accessing the database
        MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("testDB");

        //Creating a collection
        System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

        // Retrieving a collection
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection");
        System.out.println("Collection myCollection selected successfully");

        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            if (!name[i].equals("vacant") && (i == 0 || !name[i - 1].equals(name[i]))) {
                Document document = new Document("title", "Customer")
                        .append("Name", name[i])
                        .append("Seats", i + 1);
                collection.insertOne(document);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");

    }
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: You want the `name` field values from all the documents back into an array?

Comment: Yes for the load method

Answer (score 0):

I updated your `loadFile` method to get the array of names.

```
private static void loadFile(String[] name) {

    try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(System.getProperty("mongodb.uri"))) {

        MongoDatabase sampleTrainingDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDB");
        MongoCollection<Document> gradesCollection = sampleTrainingDB.getCollection("collection");

         // find one document with new Document
        Document document = gradesCollection.find(new Document("title", "Customer")).first();

        /** Code added from here to the end of the method      **/  
        /** Find all documents and get the names into an array **/

        // First we will load the documents in to a List collection
        List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
        gradesCollection.find(new Document("title", "Customer"))
                        .into(list);
        // From the list of we extract the name field and store in a string array
        String [] names = list.stream()
                               .map(doc -> doc.get("name"))
                               .toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    }
}
```

Note that I also made change to the `MongoClient` creation method.